# php -> removing anything within and including brackets

Tags: php, regex

How would I strip everything from a string the is within () but also delete them () themselves

so -  `Hello (123)` would just be `Hello`

I have tried to use the following but it only removes letter and I would like to remove both letters and numbers

```
preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$getplacename22 ->childNodes->item(4)->textContent);
```

Comment: Works fine for me http://codepad.viper-7.com/oqEPNH

Answer (score 1):

Should be like;

```
preg_replace("/\(.*\)/s","",$getplacename22 ->childNodes->item(4)->textContent);
```

This will strip everything in paranteheses including the parantehes themselves. You don't need to use or escape braces.

Answer (score 0):

You have not escaped the closing bracket in your range block.

The following code will match opening bracket, any text and a closing bracket:

```
$output = preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)/", '', $input);
```

For those who can't read regex:

```
\( //Opening bracket. The "\" is escaping the bracket so we can select it
    [ //This tells regex to select a range of characters
        ^ // This is a logical NOT character
        \) // So, select anything that is not a closing bracket. (remember to escape it)
    ]+ // select none or more characters
\) //closing bracket
```

Comment: You don't need to escape round brackets inside a character class.